# Is there a way to prevent jQuery event bubbling to a particular div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the following code, is there a way to allow everything to receive the event minus the `div`, when the *Hello* is clicked?

***HTML :***

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>
        <a href="#">
            <span>Hello</span>
        </a>
    </h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***JavaScript :***

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var els = document.querySelectorAll("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            alert('Click event fired on the ' + this.nodeName + ' element');
        });
    }
});
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DW6Jn/)

Comment: Why listen on windows.click? why not use jquery's click handler and attach it to just the span you want it on?

Comment: How can I add logic to the click handler itself?

Comment: The CSS in your question is actually JavaScript. Not only that, but it's also JavaScript that is different from the JavaScript in your fiddle.

Comment: Do you want the body and html elements to receive the event?

Comment: @Matijs: Yes, I do want everything else to receive the event.

Comment: Events bubble up the DOM, so if you want them to reach the body and html elements, I don't think you can skip the div element. Is there a reason you don't want the event to reach the div?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `*:not(div)` selector :

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll("*:not(div)")
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DW6Jn/84/)

Comment: If the div had an id would it be, ("*:not(#theIDofDiv)"?

Comment: I will be selecting this as my answer when stackoverflow allows me.

Answer (score 3):

You have added jQuery as your tag, so why not use it? Here's your example modified:

http://jsfiddle.net/DW6Jn/85/

```
$(function(){
    $('span').click(function(){
        alert('Click event fired on the ' + this.nodeName + ' element');
    })
});
```

This should not bubble,  no more looping, and jQuery gives you much cleaner way to target elements :)

UPDATE

To listen to `<h1>` all it's childeren , just listen on h1.. like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/DW6Jn/86/

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I want it to propagate excluding a single div.

Comment: I see. but still, I feel its cleaner using jquery, why not listen on the top most element you want to capture, it will capture all the ones inside, and still be lot cleaner. I have updated the answer.. just listen on h1 .. no?